# Test automation statistics

Tags: automated-testing, quality-assurance, communication

Does anyone have statistics about test automation?
In the last World Quality Report (October 2017) I read those ones:

- 48% of companies (>1000 employees) suffer from too much reliance on manual testing.
- 16% is the average level of automation of test activities (I wonder how they came up with this number though. And I don't think it's a good indicator either).

But obviously, I want moar.

For example, I would like to know who's actually automating tests (percentage of medium and small IT companies?), with which tools.

A bit of context: it's a client of mine which is asking those questions. We explained him the pros and cons, we showed him a demo and pointed out some success and failure factors. I think he's becoming aware of test automation benefits but he may need to check whether it's an actual thing !

And, to be honest, I love statistics too, especially when I know how they were "made". So feel free to share any of it here.

**EDIT** : Wow, I finally found something! State of Testing survey 2017: http://qablog.practitest.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/State_of_testing_2017_final_report.pdf

Comment: This kind of "survey" question is not a good fit for this forum - we are looking for questions that can have a most correct answer. Please see the Help Center https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for more information.

Comment: While "survey" questions are excluded, it would be interesting to read about the answer. Even if your question will likely will get closed, hint to OP: let us know what you found. I think that we should make exception for **this** survey. OP, reply to me if it get's closed and I will vote to reopen it.

Comment: I suggest this question to be reopened: IMHO it did not deserved to be closed. **OP found interesting answer** and deserves some good karma for coming back and self-answering it. Also, the **answer might be useful for future readers, because is directly relevant to our audience**. Seriously guys, it is not first time your names are associated with closing salveable questions. If we chase away questions relevant to QA, we will become xpath help link. It *that* your secret goal?

Answer (score 0):

It is not full answer, but https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/ has some hints.

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for your answer as well as your support. I've Ctrl+F quite many test-oriented keywords on this survey, but I didn't find anything relevant about test automation...

Comment: I finally found something here :) http://qablog.practitest.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/State_of_testing_2017_final_report.pdf